# What are the most common ways that COVID kills?

Tags: covid-19, statistics, death, covid-19-datasets, pneumonia

Looking at the death counts for 2020 published on [the CDC's website](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/vsrr/covid19/index.htm), total deaths "involving COVID-19" were 375,581, but total deaths "involving COVID-19 and pneumonia" were only 175,653.

So if less than half of all COVID deaths were caused by pneumonia, what were the rest caused by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same CDC website, there is a section titled:

> [COVID-19 Mortality Overview](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/covid19/mortality-overview.htm)

A link on this page (last but one) leads to a detailed analysis of comorbidalities:

> [Most Frequently Listed Comorbidities with COVID-19 Deaths](https://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nvss/vsrr/covid_weekly/index.htm#Comorbidities)

and also adds that as of 2nd Feb 2021, deaths involving:

- Influenza/Pneumonia (44%)
- Hypertension (20%)
- Diabetes (16%)
- Dementias (15%)
- Sepsis (9%)

i.e. the patients already had these illnesses **before** catching COVID-19, and later died.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out explicitly that just because a cause of death does not include "pneumonia" does not mean pneumonia was not present. If listed alongside COVID-19 it may be that the person listing cause of death considered it redundant to write both.